compiled Gatsby files
I'm new to gatsby, and i have a problem
I followed all the steps in the quick start guide, but when doing sudo docker compose up --build in the root folder of the project, I receive the following error:
git clone git@github.com:gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git
cd gatsby-starter-default
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 -v ${PWD}:/site --name gatsby datawookie/gatsby:latest

This is the error:
⠏ compile gatsby files
/site/node_modules/yoga-layout-prebuilt/yoga-layout/build/Release/nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error: Initiated Worker with invalid execArgv flags: --no-opt
    at new Worker (node:internal/worker:222:13)
    at ThreadsWorker.start (/site/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/threads/ThreadsWorker.js:51:19)
    at Worker.fork (/site/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/Worker.js:105:23)
    at WorkerFarm.startChild (/site/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/WorkerFarm.js:248:12)
    at WorkerFarm.startMaxWorkers (/site/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/WorkerFarm.js:420:14)
    at new WorkerFarm (/site/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/WorkerFarm.js:149:10)
    at createWorkerFarm (/site/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Parcel.js:568:10)
    at Parcel._init (/site/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Parcel.js:232:20)
    at Parcel.run (/site/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Parcel.js:273:7)
    at Object.runParcel (/site/node_modules/gatsby/src/utils/parcel/compile-gatsby-files.ts:66:27) {
  code: 'ERR_WORKER_INVALID_EXEC_ARGV'
}

Any idea ?
Thanks
REgards


Do you know what node version are you using?
